# Can I have 2 curve guides to make particles go 2 different ways?

Tags: particles, bezier-curves, force-fields

So when I use curves as force fields Curve Guides, the particles tend to go only one way. Is there a way to make two separate curve guides, so the half of the particles will follow one path and another half will follow another path?

[image]

Comment: Make two identical particle systems one for each curve each with half the total particle count?

Comment: But how do I attach particles to curve?

Comment: [Google Search is your friend](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYHOV3bVIG0)